# How To create a file (containing XML or JSON data )into system folder using angular 7

Tags: xml, angular, typescript

I have XML data that which i want to save in a file in my angular 7 project.

I am trying to use ,

```
fs = require('fs');
```

but getting error, `Cannot find module 'fs'.`

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var ws = fs.createWriteStream('../../assets/Templates/foo.xml');
```

i wanted to create a file with name foo.xml with XML data